# Import stand alone Rmd (own repo and project) as a post in blogdown?

Tags: r, git, blogdown

Most of my analysis is done using the "1 project = 1 repository" approach. In each of these repository, there is a single R project and often a single Rmd file generating a html_document where all the analysis lives.

Some of these analysis would make good blog post, and I'd like the blog post to be updated if I ever update the analysis.

Is there a way to create a blog post from this analysis without re-doing all of it inside the blog's project and repo?

I tried cloning the "analysis repo" into blogdown's /content folder, but all I ended up was the year "0001" on my blog's home page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not impossible, but it can be very tricky, and I don't recommend you to do it. Instead, put the `.html` (and associated dependencies, if any) output file under the `static/` directory of your blogdown website (see [Section 2.7](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html) of the **blogdown** book), write a short post under `content/`, and link to the `.html` file in the short post.

You can certainly automate this job (copying files from the original directory to `static/`) in the R script `R/build.R` (see [Appendix D.9](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html)). I think it will be a lot easier if you could just put the `.Rmd` source documents under `static/`, so that you don't even need to copy files from one directory to another (again, see Section 2.7).

Comment: Thanks Yihui!  I'll implement your approach - thanks for this!